# problem running virtual machines on ubuntu 12.04 via virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 last week. Now I want to use Windows 7 on Ubuntu via Virtualbox. I installed the Virtualbox and created a new machine namely 'windows 7'. I'm booting through an ISO image. When I start the virtual machine it does not run. It gives the following 2 errors:

```
"Failed to open a session for the virtual machine mint.
The virtual machine 'mint' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1.
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Machine
Interface: 
IMachine {5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91}".
```

and

```
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary."
```

I have no idea that how to fix it. I tried running other OS as well like Linux Mint 12 but same error occurs. Please help!!!!

Comment: You have probably received an update of your kernel, so you need to install vbox kernel modules to it. Have you tried running, what it says: `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`?

Comment: Can you help he intalling the vbox kernel modules? 
I already tried the command you said but it gives an error
sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found

Comment: strange output. Please edit your post and copy-paste everything there is on terminal when you run this command including command itself.

Comment: me@delta:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found 
me@delta:~$

Comment: i can't reproduce the issue. Maybe VirtualBox installation is corrupt - try removing it and reinstalling using Software Center or with a package from official site.

Comment: it worked.. I run the ls commad in init.d directory. Found that there was no such folder as vboxdrv. Instead virtualbox directory was there. By changing the directory name in command worked! :) Thanks

Comment: Glad you have solved the problem :) Just want to add, so that you know - there are typically no directories in /etc/init.d/ and vboxdrv is not a directory as well - they are executable scripts (known as 'Init scripts') that accept a certain enumeration of commands.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a known issue.
Try to install VirtualBox from the Oracle binaries directly: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

sources: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1739768

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue a while ago, so please check the following:

1. Check the BIOS settings and enable something called "Intel Virtualisation Technology" if you have an Intel CPU, or any other setting that reffers to vitualisation, CPU pass through.
2. Make sure you leave the default setting for the virtual machine as Oracle VB sets them.
3. Remove the currently installed VB, and try the one on the official website.

In my case I had to install the VB from the website, issue solved.

Please post an answer and let know if anything worked. Take care.